# How to execute a line of code if a double has an integer value in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

I want to use an if condition that executes a line of code depending on whether or not a certain double has an integer value:

```
int A;
int B;
int C;
double X;

cout << "Enter three values: " << endl;
cin >> A >> B >> C;

X=A*B*C;
X=sqrt(X);

if (X holds an integer value){
    //Do this
}
else if (X does not hold an integer value){
    //Do this instead
}
```

Basically I can't work out how to write the if condition. Is there a simple syntax I can use to do this, or do I need to add some separate code to check the double and then pass a boolean to the if condition?

Many thanks in advance. I have checked elsewhere on here but can only find examples where people wanted to cout the result of the check, rather than use it in a condition. This was generally done by truncating the double in some way or examining it as a string, none of which will work here I believe.

I am working in Visual Studio 2013 and Windows 8.1.

Any help appreciated.

[Edit: I've added the sqrt function alluded to in the comments to the accepted solution]

Comment: If you are multiplying three `int`s, you can't have a non integer value (except for things like `nan` or infinity).

Comment: integer in the sense of ℕ, or the data type int (32/64 bit integer number)? Also, what's your restriction on precision?

Comment: @crashmstr Its worth mentioning that, because of the way doubles work, even multiplying three ints could result in a non integer value stored in X

Comment: @mebob yes, while the double itself could be `13.999999` or something, the fact that the example starts with multiplying `int` variables makes this unclear as to the purpose (to big for an `int` to hold?)

Comment: Thanks @Bathsheba for adding in the square root. Exactly what I means :)

Comment: Have done so now - apologies, was away for some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the main uses of `modf`:

```
bool
isInt( double d )
{
    double dummy;
    return modf( d, &dummy ) == 0.0;
}
```

Of course, this solution is exact; in many cases, you'll want to accept some sort of epsilon, since the floating pont arithmetic won't have been exact.

Comment: Thanks for this - now accepted. I had been away from SO for some time otherwise would have accepted earlier. Many thanks.

Comment: Why would you want an exact comparison of an inexact operation? Not intended as an accusation, just no idea why you would ever want that.

Comment: @wolfPack88 Because there is no inexact operation in the given code.

Answer (score 2):

Round the double and compare it to the original double. I.e.,

```
if(fabs(round(X) - X) < 0.001)
```

Obviously, you can change the tolerance to whatever you feel is acceptable. Also, as crashmstr pointed out in the comments, there is no way to get a non-integer value if you multiply three integers.

Comment: Thanks, simple in the end! As for getting non-integer values from multiplying integers: sorry, I missed a line of code out - X should have been square rooted and THEN checked for integers, but thanks for pointing it out anyway. The code is working out a treat.

Answer (score -2):

Create a simple function:

```
bool isInt(double n) {
    if (int (n) == n)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Usually `==` doesn't work well with `double` and `float`

Comment: never compare double values using equals

Comment: would I then follow that up for my main if condition with if(isInt=true){ //do this}....etc. ?

Comment: @GuyStimpson Never compare `double` with `==`.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison) if you want to compare `double`s

Comment: @GuyStimpson: 1) Don't compare `double` with `==` as already mentioned. Also, 2) you can just use `if(isInt)`, provided you code the comparison in a manner similar to either my post above, or the post gongzhitaao linked to.

Comment: @gongzhitaao I wasn't aware of such problems with floating point numbers.

Comment: @MatthiasB That's not a good rule.  It depends on what you're doing.

Comment: @JamesKanze if you know for yourself that you have a case where you need to compare with `==`, you know enough to descard this rule. In any other case it will save you a lot of trouble, hidden bugs and long debugging.

Comment: @MatthiasB If you don't know enough about floating point to know when you can compare using `==`, and when you can't, then you don't know enough to use floating point to begin with (except for certain trivial uses).

Comment: @JamesKanze I disagree. For an example you just have to look at this answer. You will get to a point where you want to check two numbers for equality. And I don't see how everyone who gets to such a point will be a floating point expert. But to be honest, I don't know too much about floating points myself, so my view might be wrong and limited.

Comment: @MatthiasB It isn't easy.  There are simple things that you can do without much knowledge.  But when it comes to comparison... You do have to know what you're doing in order to choose between exact equality, a fixed epsilon or a relative one.  And in the latter two cases, you really have to be aware of the implications (e.g. that the comparison is no longer transitive).  (In the case the original poster presented, testing whether the square root of the product of three integers is a whole number, I'd opt for exact equality.)

Answer (score -2):

Is this what you are looking for ?

string x = "42";

int value;

if(int.TryParse(x, out value))

// Do something

Comment: It is not `java` or `C#` where `int` object has a methods.

Comment: Are you sure this is c++?

Comment: oh ow sorry , overseen the c++ , thought it was c# , my mistake ^^